# Computing overhead of statistical models for training?

Tags: machine-learning, model

Could someone provide overhead of the following model for training (With respect to input size or if there are any relevant parameters). Overhead I mean somewhat like asymptotic time complexity form.

1. Multiple linear regression models (Least Sqaures)
2. Decision Tree (C 4.5 OR ID3)
3. K nearest neighbor

Thank you.

Comment: This question needs additional information and clarification.  What are you attempting to *calculate* with these models?  What forms will your data be given in?  What are "C 4.5" and "K-nn"?  Note that in statistics a "model" is a mathematical description of data; it is not an algorithm and therefore the concept of algorithmic complexity does not apply *per se*.

Comment: Thanks for your thoughts. I would like to know the time complexity of training in these models.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What algorithm is used in linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1829/what-algorithm-is-used-in-linear-regression) and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282558/algorithmic-complexity-big-o-of-cart-tree-building and https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219655/k-nn-computational-complexity

Answer (score 1):

## Linear regression

The complexity of linear regression depends on how you choose to solve the problem. This is a well-studied problem, and different methods are optimal in different contexts.

[What algorithm is used in linear regression?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1829/what-algorithm-is-used-in-linear-regression)

## Decision Tree

[Algorithmic complexity (big-O) of CART tree building](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/282558/algorithmic-complexity-big-o-of-cart-tree-building)

## K-NN

[k-NN computational complexity](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/219655/k-nn-computational-complexity)