# k-NN computational complexity

Tags: k-nearest-neighbour, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of the *k*-NN algorithm with naive search approach (no k-d tree or similars)?

I am interested in its time complexity considering also the hyperparameter *k*. I have found contradictory answers:

1. O(nd + kn), where *n* is the cardinality of the training set and *d* the dimension of each sample. [1]
2. O(ndk), where again *n* is the cardinality of the training set and *d* the dimension of each sample. [2]

[1] http://www.csd.uwo.ca/courses/CS9840a/Lecture2_knn.pdf (Pag. 18/20)

[2] http://www.cs.haifa.ac.il/~rita/ml_course/lectures/KNN.pdf (Pag. 18/31)

Answer (score 42, accepted):

Assuming $k$ is fixed (as both of the linked lectures do), then your algorithmic choices will determine whether your computation takes $O(nd+kn)$ runtime or $O(ndk)$ runtime.

First, let's consider a $O(nd+kn)$ runtime algorithm:

- Initialize $selected_i = 0$ for all observations $i$ in the training set
- For each training set observation $i$, compute $dist_i$, the distance from the new observation to training set observation $i$
- For $j=1$ to $k$: Loop through all training set observations, selecting the index $i$ with the smallest $dist_i$ value and for which $selected_i=0$. Select this observation by setting $selected_i=1$.
- Return the $k$ selected indices

Each distance computation requires $O(d)$ runtime, so the second step requires $O(nd)$ runtime. For each iterate in the third step, we perform $O(n)$ work by looping through the training set observations, so the step overall requires $O(nk)$ work. The first and fourth steps only require $O(n)$ work, so we get a $O(nd+kn)$ runtime.

Now, let's consider a $O(ndk)$ runtime algorithm:

- Initialize $selected_i = 0$ for all observations $i$ in the training set
- For $j=1$ to $k$: Loop through all training set observations and compute the distance $d$ between the selected training set observation and the new observation. Select the index $i$ with the smallest $d$ value for which $selected_i=0$. Select this observation by setting $selected_i=1$.
- Return the $k$ selected indices

For each iterate in the second step, we compute the distance between the new observation and each training set observation, requiring $O(nd)$ work for an iteration and therefore $O(ndk)$ work overall.

The difference between the two algorithms is that the first precomputes and stores the distances (requiring $O(n)$ extra memory), while the second does not. However, given that we already store the entire training set, requiring $O(nd)$ memory, as well as the $selected$ vector, requiring $O(n)$ storage, the storage of the two algorithms is asymptotically the same. As a result, the better asymptotic runtime for $k > 1$ makes the first algorithm more attractive.

It's worth noting that it is possible to obtain an $O(nd)$ runtime using an algorithmic improvement:

- For each training set observation $i$, compute $dist_i$, the distance from the new observation to training set observation $i$
- Run the [quickselect algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians) to compute the $k^{th}$ smallest distance in $O(n)$ runtime
- Return all indices no larger than the computed $k^{th}$ smallest distance

This approach takes advantage of the fact that efficient approaches exist to find the $k^{th}$ smallest value in an unsorted array.

Comment: Great answer and I especially like the advice towards the use of `quickselect`.

Comment: One more question: for the third option I believe that the time complexity should be O(nd+k), as you still have to compute the most common label among the k-nearest neighbors to emit a prediction, right?

Comment: @Daniel Since $k \leq n$, $O(nd+k)$ is the same as $O(nd)$.

Comment: Last time I bother you: trying to determine the computational complexity of a modified version of *k*-NN I am working on, I get the following:

*O(nd+nd/p)*

Where by definition *n*, *d* and *p* are integers greater than zero. Can I simplify that to *O(nd)*?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, in that case $O(nd)$ works.

Comment: `quickselect` has a worst-case complexity $O(n^2)$ and an average-case complexity $O(n)$. So shouldn't we use $O(n^2)$ in calculating the KNN complexity?

Comment: Is it true that in the CS context people tend to use worst-case complexity while in the machine learning context people tend to use average-case complexity?

Comment: @LeiHuang quickselect has worst case $O(n)$ complexity -- see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_of_medians

Comment: It says $O(n^2)$ here: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickselect

Comment: @LeiHuang I'm sure it depends on the version of quickselect used, but for instance http://people.csail.mit.edu/rivest/pubs/BFPRT73.pdf presents a version that is worst-case $O(n)$, since from the abstract we read that at most $5.43n$ comparisons are ever required.

Comment: Your answer begins with "Assuming  is fixed (as both of the linked lectures do), then your algorithmic choices will determine whether your computation takes (+) runtime or () runtime.". But if  is a constant, then: (+) = () = (). So I'm not sure what you mean by "Assuming  is fixed".

Comment: @Stef I guess I just meant that it's not being estimated from data, e.g. via a scree plot.