# How is the linear regression optimize in R and Python?

Tags: r, regression, python, optimization

I am currently working a lot with R and Python. I am not able to access the C code the the R function lm_fit. I am wondering how is the linear regression optimize in R and python ?

I am pretty sure in R it is optimize with the Normal equation (since R is good with matrix multiplication) and I would think it is optimize with Gradient descent in Python ?

Am I right ?

Answer (score 2):

By default `lm` uses QR decomposition, but there are other options available -- see the documentation. Using the normal equations is a pretty bad way to solve this problem because of problems related to numerical precision; this point is covered extensively on Stats.SE. [See this thread for an example](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1829/what-algorithm-is-used-in-linear-regression/1882#1882).

There are several OLS and GLM implementations in Python so there's no single answer to that question.

Answer (score 1):

R uses QR decomposition. My answer [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/278779/113777) has some useful links on how to solve a least square problem.

Also, check this awesome answer for the details of `lm`. [Least Squares Regression Step-By-Step Linear Algebra Computation](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/154485/least-squares-regression-step-by-step-linear-algebra-computation/154514#154514).

Finally, I do not think you can find the C code, since it uses basic linear algebra package such as BLAS / LAPACK, many of them are compiled and the source is in FORTRAN. Check slide 4 in [this link](https://web.stanford.edu/class/ee392o/nlas-foils.pdf).